# Postgres update column only if column of same value does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to do a simple update operation on some columns in a join table on my DB, however, I do not want to make the update if a column with the updated value already exists.

So say the join table looks something like this:

```
_id | fkId
----------
1   | A
1   | B
2   | B
3   | C
3   | B
4   | A
```

- I want to update all the entries that have the `fkId` of `B`, to `A`
- However, each entry must be unique, so if I already have another entry for that same `_id` already set to `fkId` `A`, then I don't want to do the update but instead just get rid of it

My update currently looks like the following:

```
  UPDATE my_table
  SET "fkId"='A'
  WHERE "fkId"='B';
```

In my example table above you see entry of `_id` `1`, so if I run this query I will end up with two entries as

```
_id | fkId
----------
1   | A
1   | A
```

I do **not** want this. Each pair needs to be unique, so it must be deleted. How can I have this happen through a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not exists` condition additionally:

```
UPDATE my_table AS t
  SET "fkId"='A'
  WHERE "fkId"='B' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from my_table WHERE _id=t._id AND "fkId" = 'A');
```

Then, if you want to delete rows that not updated - just do it:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE "fkId" = 'B';
```

To avoid interventions from parallel sessions between those two queries you probably need to lock rows before:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE "fkId" = 'B' FOR UPDATE;
```

So your whole statements sequence could be:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE "fkId" = 'B' FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE my_table AS t
  SET "fkId"='A'
  WHERE "fkId"='B' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from my_table WHERE _id=t._id AND "fkId" = 'A');
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE "fkId" = 'B';
COMMIT;
```